# Pyspark - Padding zeros of array int datatype without pandas udf

Tags: pyspark

Need to left padding in Array column of pyspark dataframe without using pandasudf.

```
Input Dataframe:
|lags|
|----|
|[0]|
|[0,1,2]|
|[0,1]|

Output Data frame:
|lags|
|----|
|[0,0,0]|
|[0,1,2]|
|[0,0,1]|
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_repeat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat.html) to create zero padding array and `concat` them.

Use @ARCrow's function to identify the max array size.

```py
max_arr_size = 3

df = (df.withColumn('pad', F.array_repeat(F.lit(0), max_arr_size - F.size('lags')))
      .withColumn('padded', F.concat('pad', 'lags')))
```

Comment: On top of array repeat, i used flatten to make it as one array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ([0],),
    ([0,1,2],),
    ([0,1],),
    (None,)
], ['lags'])

max_size = (df
            .withColumn('array_size', f.size(f.col('lags')))
            .groupBy()
            .agg(f.max(f.col('array_size')).alias('max_size'))
            .collect()[0].max_size
           )
df = (df
      .withColumn('lags', f.when(f.col('lags').isNull(), f.array(*[])).otherwise(f.col('lags'))) #to deal with null values
      .withColumn('pre_zeros', f.sequence(f.lit(0), f.lit(max_size) - f.size(f.col('lags'))))
      .withColumn('zeros', f.expr('transform(slice(pre_zeros, 1, size(pre_zeros) - 1), element -> 0)'))
      .withColumn('final_lags', f.concat(f.col('zeros'), f.col('lags')))
     )

df.show()
```

And the output is:

```
+---------+------------+---------+----------+
|     lags|   pre_zeros|    zeros|final_lags|
+---------+------------+---------+----------+
|      [0]|   [0, 1, 2]|   [0, 0]| [0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 1, 2]|         [0]|       []| [0, 1, 2]|
|   [0, 1]|      [0, 1]|      [0]| [0, 0, 1]|
|       []|[0, 1, 2, 3]|[0, 0, 0]| [0, 0, 0]|
+---------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: @Emma's answer is more efficient. I didn't think of array_repeat transformation.